# How can you be so sure the rank of T is definable?

Tags: linear-algebra

The rank of a linear transformation from V into W is defined:

> If V is finite-dimensional, the *rank* of T is the dimension of the range of T and ...

However, there is no guarantee the range of T is finite-dimensional, in which case the dimension of it cannot be defined.

Comment: Note that the rank of $T$ is always smaller than $\dim V$. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rank%E2%80%93nullity_theorem

Comment: If set $S$ spans $V$, it's image $T(S)$ obviously spans the range.

Answer (score 1):

It is finite as the space  $V$ is finite dimensional and the images under $T$ of the elements of a generating set of $V$ will be a generating set of the range.

Answer (score 1):

If $\{v_1,v_2,\cdots,v_n\}$ is a basis of $V,$ then $\{Tv_1, Tv_2, \cdots,Tv_n \}$ will span $T(V).$
As basis is a minimal spanning set, $T(V)$ will also be finite dimensional.